# how to get following json in android

Tags: android, json, retrofit

> How to get this json in android.

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        "1",
        "4",
        "5"
    ]
}
```

> I didn't get this json android how to get it please help me

Comment: Do you mean how to convert to models

Comment: how to get it using post method of retrofit in android

Comment: [Read up on it.](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first you will create object with

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

We will create object :

```
 package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Boolean status;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<String> data = null;

public Boolean getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
this.status = status;
}

public List<String> getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(List<String> data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```

After you will get data from object with code:

```
 // Deserialize to single object.
public Example deserializeFromJson(String jsonString) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Example myClass = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Example.class);
    return myClass;
}
```

I hope it can help your problem!

Answer (score 0):

> You can Archive like this

```
public class Demo {



@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Boolean status;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<String> data = null;

public Boolean getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
this.status = status;
}

public List<String> getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(List<String> data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```